# How to find the HTML file with Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome DevTools, I can't find any HTML file when inspecting the network tab on investopedia.com.

How to find the HTML file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not alway an HTML file. For example with investopedia.com, the HTML content is obtained from the https://www.investopedia.com URL, but there is no HTML file.

With the Chrome DevTool you can [filter by resource type](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network#type). If you click on "Doc", you will see only requests returning HTML content.